# Is it possible to add additional parameters to event methods?

Tags: c#, events

I have event method `eventManager_ServiceFound` then inside that method there is event assigned to the method `eventManager_ServiceResolved` and I would like to pass to that method some additional parameters from method `eventManager_ServiceFound`.

Something like:

`static void eventManager_ServiceResolved(parameters which are already there, string domain(form eventManager_ServiceFound))`.

How the code looks:

```
  public static void ScanService() {
            try {
                service = new DNSSDService();
                eventManager = new DNSSDEventManager();
                eventManager.ServiceFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceFoundEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceFound);

                browse = service.Browse(0, 0, "_axis-video._tcp", null, eventManager);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }



        static void eventManager_ServiceFound(DNSSDService browser, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string serviceName, string regtype, string domain) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("---------------- eventManager_ServiceFound------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("browser: " + browser + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifIndex " + ifIndex + "\nserviceName: " + serviceName + "\nregtype: " + regtype + "\ndomain: " + domain);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

                //   DNSSDService service2 = new DNSSDService();
                eventManager.ServiceResolved += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceResolvedEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceResolved);
                browser.Resolve(flags, ifIndex, serviceName, regtype, domain, eventManager);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION--------eventManager_ServiceFound---------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }

        private static void eventManager_ServiceResolved(DNSSDService service, DNSSDFlags flags, uint ifIndex, string fullname, string hostname, ushort port, TXTRecord record) {
            try {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------eventManager_ServiceResolved---------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("DNSSDService " + service + "\nDNSSDFlags " + flags + "\nifindex " + ifIndex + "\nfullname " + fullname + "hostname " + hostname + "\nport " + port + "\nrecord " + record);
                var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(record.GetValueForKey("macaddress"));
                Console.WriteLine("mac " + str);
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

                //    DNSSDService service2 = new DNSSDService();
                eventManager.AddressFound += new _IDNSSDEvents_AddressFoundEventHandler(eventManager_AddressFound);
                DNSSDAddressFamily family = new DNSSDAddressFamily();
                service.GetAddrInfo(flags, ifIndex, family, hostname, eventManager);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION--------eventManager_ServiceResolved---------");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("--------------------EXCEPTION-----------------");
            }
        }
```

EDIT:

```
   eventManager.ServiceResolved += new _IDNSSDEvents_ServiceResolvedEventHandler(eventManager_ServiceResolved);//how to convert this line into this one below
            eventManager.ServiceResolved += (x, y, z) => eventManager_ServiceResolved(x, y, z, a, b, c);
            browser.Resolve(flags, ifIndex, serviceName, regtype, domain, eventManager);
```

EDIT2:

There will be only one fire of service resolved for one fire of service found. But there will be many service found fires

Answer (score 1):

Use a lambda:

```
eventManager.ServiceResolved += (x, y, z) => eventManager_ServiceResolved(x, y, z, a, b, c);
```

Comment: I don't understand lambda notation to well. Could you please look at the EDIT in original post please and show me how use this in practice. Please(it's not the first day I fight with it.)

Comment: This will be a one-time passthrough as the lambda is elevated to a class. You would probably want to call methods to retrieve `a,b,c` so that it's lazy (or have them resolve to properties of an object).

Comment: No no.. it should work. What I mean is that where Ondrej has provided `a,b,c` in his example.. you will probably require that they actually be method calls to retrieve a value. Otherwise, they will be captured once and never update (which is what I assume you want).

Comment: Btw: +1 for thinking outside the box.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead There will be only one fire of service resolved for one fire of service found. But there will be many service found fires.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The library I use is Apple's bonjour 1.0. It is COM object.